# How to know is PhpStorm is using my video card

Tags: indexing, phpstorm, video-card

I know that PhpStorm can use my video card to index my code.

So I want to know is PhpStorm uses my video card to index my code. And if it is not - how to do it?
My OS is Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS. My PHPStorm version is 2016.1. My NVidia driver version is 340

Comment: *"I know that PhpStorm can use my video card to index my code"* Where did you read that? Can you share some links, please? ALSO -- do not forget to state your OS and PhpStorm version used.